# How to pass object in another Component and redirect in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Product List. I want to edit a product with click on a Edit Button. With Edit Button I am firing a Function.

```
UpdateProduct(product) {
   eventBus.$emit('product', product);
   this.$router.push('products/add');
}
```

But this product is not accessible in Edit Product Component. Testing via Add Product Component.

But this eventBus is not working on that Component.

```
created() {
   eventBus.$on('product', (product) => {
      this.editProduct = product;
      console.log(this.editProduct)
   })
}
```

What should be the approach to do that?

N.B: I have registered the eventBus in both components.

Answer (score 2):

If you have named your route. You can try with another way

You can pass `product` object as a router param

```js
    edit (product) {
       this.$router.push({ name: 'products/edit', params: { product: product }})
    }
```

You can get product on redirected page

```js
    created () {
        console.log(this.$route.params.product)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
eventBus.$on("product", product => {
  this.$data.editProduct = product; // USE $data before
  this.$forceUpdate(); //this is predefined function in Vue
});
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.